# Проблемы с запуском Celery-задач в асинхронной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, celery

В проекте, в качестве endpoint'ов используются асинхронные функции.
Есть необходимость запускать Celery-задачу внутри endpoint'а.

Функция (celery task):

```
@celery_app.task
def some_celery_func(arg1):
    ...
```

Запускаю её внутри асинхронной функции (endpoint'а) следующей командой:

```
some_celery_func.delay(11)
```

В терминале запущен воркер: `celery -A <myproj> worker -E -l INFO` 
Версия Celery: 4.4.0
Версия Python: 3.7

**Проблема:**
Celery задача запускается, в буквальном смысле, через раз.

**Вопрос:**
В чём может быть проблема и как её возможно разрешить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установил причину такого поведения.
Дело в том, что worker'ы подвисли и "превратились в демонов" оторвавшись от родительского процесса.

Как выяснил:

- Отключил worker в терминале.
- Открыл админ-панель rabbitmq.
- Открыл "Очередь" -> выбрал главную очередь.

Инициировал запуск Celery-задачи.

В графике увидел, что не смотря на то, что мой worker выключен rabbitmq принял запрос и обработал его.
В терминале, с помощью **htop**, просмотрел текущие процессы и треды.
Принудительно завершил подвешанные worker'ы.

Далее:

- Запустил worker в терминале.
- Повторно инициировал несколько запусков Celery-задачи.
- В графике и в терминале увидел, что все задачи успешной отработаны.

В принципе типичная проблема, но до последнего был уверен, что дело в используемом асинхронном коде приложения.